# bad key error occurred when tried to fetch data from api endpoint in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I tried to fetch data from api endpoint using `request`, but I got a bad key error. In my case, I provided api-key and endpoint url, so I used `request` to get `json` content of the data then used `pandas` to create data frame. I looked into `SO` but didn't find a clue how to get over this. Does anyone have possible thoughts or attempts to fix this? How can I correctly fetch data from api endpoint? Any idea?

**my attempt**

I tried to fetch data from this site: [market data](https://apps.fas.usda.gov/opendataweb/home)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_key = 'ec95a478-e46e-47f9-b57d-3d19012d527d'
url = 'https://apps.fas.usda.gov/OpenData/api/esr/countries'
headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{key}'.format(key=api_key)}
jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(jsonData)
```

but I got this error after running the above codes:

> 'Bad API Key'

I accessed to [this api](https://apps.fas.usda.gov/opendataweb/home) and got this instruction as follow:

> Hello Adam, your custom API key is
> ********-****-****-****-3d19012d527d Show Please copy and paste your API key into api_key text box in Swagger window below and start
> exploring the API. Please ues your custom key as name value pair
> API_KEY:Value in HTTP Header, when making API request from your
> applications.

where am I wrong in my above attempt? How can I correctly fetch data from any API endpoint on [this site](https://apps.fas.usda.gov/opendataweb/home)? Can anyone suggest a possible way of fetching data from api endpoints with `json`, `request`, and `pandas`? Any thoughts?

Comment: Do this instead: `headers = {'API_KEY': '{key}'.format(key=api_key)}` as specified in their message.

Comment: side note: you probably don't want to have your API key shown in plain text here

Comment: @PaulH how can I fetch data from multiple endpoints into one pandas dataframe? Do you mind making a possible answer on that? Thanks a lot

Comment: There are many questions on SO about using `pandas.concat` to build up dataframes. I recommend searching through those first.

Comment: @PaulH right, but seems there is no direct way to fetch data by loop through top n api endpoints. Is that doable to fetch data from top 5 api endpoints and build dataframe from it instead of giving each urls manually? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes it's doable, but I'm not sure what it has to do with this question. If you want some consulting to help you with a larger problem, I charge $50/hr with a 1/2 hour minimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending 1 header with your request. That header is named `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`. Judging by the sliver of email you shared they expect the header to contain a pair named `API_KEY`.

If that is the issue the following should resolve it.

```py
headers = {'API_KEY': '{key}'.format(key=api_key)}
```

Formatting a string to be the value of a string variable is redundant. Your code could be cleaned up by removing the call to `format()`

```py
headers = {'API_KEY': api_key}
```

#### One thing to keep in mind

You posted your API key on a public site. Given that API keys are used for authentication, it would be best practice to de-authenticate your current key and request a new one, to prevent unauthorized use.

Comment: I believe this is equivalent to `headers = {'API_KEY': key}`, is it not?